# Preferences don't show up in data/data nor can i access them with code

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to create a game. Now for some data i need to keep(music, effects, background on/of) i would like to use `preferences`.

I create new `xml` file named `preferences.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <EditTextPreference android:key="music" android:title="Some title" android:defaultValue="true"/>


</PreferenceScreen>
```

Then i go to the location(with root privileges) and there is only lib folder in  `data/data/my.app.folder/`. No `shared_prefs` folder.

When i try to access the preferences it is null. I tried with `getSharedPreferences()` and with  `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`. What could be the reason? 
Also i don't have activity for the `preferences`, I want to manage them manually.

How can I get over this problem?

Comment: Where are you putting that xml file? What directory in your build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use shared preferences you will have to create it first. Like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
      "music", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To create preferences in first time in it:

```
    final String BACKGROUND_DEFAULT_VALUE = "on";
    final String DEFAULT_TITILE = "";
    final String TITILE_KEY = "title";
    final String BACKGROUND_KEY = "background_key";
    Editor editor= prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(TITILE_KEY, DEFAULT_TITILE);
    editor.putString(BACKGROUND_KEY, BACKGROUND_DEFAULT_VALUE);
    editor.commit();
```

Than to edit/and save preferences in it:

```
    Editor editor= prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(TITILE_KEY, "new title");
    editor.putString(BACKGROUND_KEY, "new background value i.e on/off");
    editor.commit();
```

Than To read preferences:

```
String background_value = prefs.getString(BACKGROUND_KEY); 
String title_value = prefs.getString(TITILE_KEY );
```

And you can see your shared preference file at location, it will be there after the creation.

```
/data/data/<packagename>/shared_prefs/music.xml
```

For more details and help, The android sdk's sample directory contains an example of retrieving and stroing shared preferences. Its located in the:

```
<android-sdk-home>/samples/android-<platformversion>/ApiDemos directory
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh, thank you, for some reason i thought that by making this file i would set up the files in data/data too. This certainly makes sense :D

Answer (score 0):

There are two different types of xml files related to preferences.
The one you are showing is the xml resource file representing the preference hierarchy (screen representation).
The second one is the file containing the actual key value pairs.
Creating the first one doesn't create the second one. You'll actually need to display the file using a PreferenceActivity (or the Fragment equivalent or your own display method which - as I understand - you intend to do) or you'll have to create the preferences in code.